# Assign javascript function to a dom element

Tags: javascript, dom, vb6

I'm using the MSHTML library for parsing out HTML via `MSHTML.HTMLDocument`.

my question: is there a way to assign a JavaScript function to a DOM element?
I've tried something like:

```
div.onmouseover = "function(){alert('mouseover')}"
```

and

```
div.setattribute "onmouseover" , "function(){alert('mouseover')}"
```

without success (no error, but no effect either).

Any ideas if it's possible?

Answer (score 5):

Always use a function, rather than attaching a string of code in your javascript. You can do this by assigning an anonymous function. The function receives an event object as it's only argument, which has information about the event, if you need to know the x/y positions of where the mouse was.

```
div.onmouseover = function(event) {
    //do stuff
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried not using anonymous functions?  For example instead of

```
div.onmouseover = "function(){alert('mouseover')}"
```

Use something like

```
div.onmouseover = "alert('mouseover');"
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the

```
<script>
```

tag in your string

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the function but not invoking it. You have to invoke the function by including the invocation parentheses. Use

```
div.setattribute "onmouseover" , "function(){alert('mouseover')}()"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div.onmouseover = function(){alert("mouseover")}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use,

```
button.onclick = new Function(“someFunctionName(‘input” + counter + “‘)”);
```

instead of `function(){alert("mouseover")` , this will work for dynamic created controls.

Note the spelling difference between  `function` and `new Function`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
div.setattribute "onmouseover" , "alert('mouseover');"
```